# Is there $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ satisfies $m \arctan \frac{1}{2}+n \arctan \frac{1}{5}=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Tags: trigonometry, pi

I know that $\arctan \frac{1}{2}+\arctan \frac{1}{3}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $2\arctan \frac{1}{2}-\arctan \frac{1}{7}=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Is there $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ satisfies $m \arctan \frac{1}{2}+n \arctan \frac{1}{5}=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

Comment: There is also $$4\arctan\left(\frac{1}{5}\right) - \arctan\left( \frac{1}{239}\right) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: We have many more such identities with more terms. For example $$\dfrac{\pi}{4}=8\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{10}\right)-\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{239}\right)-4\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{515}\right).$$ So, the much more interesting question would be finding rational multiples of $\pi$ for which the $\tan$ is also rational.  You can find more about this from [here.](https://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/tanpap.pdf) Even though I haven't study it before, seems very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Størmer in 1899](http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_1899__27_/BSMF_1899__27__160_1/BSMF_1899__27__160_1.pdf) (see also [Wikipedia's section on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machin-like_formula#Two-term_formulas)) showed that there are only four two-term Machin-like formulas with unit numerators for arctangent arguments:

- the two identities you listed
- the identity listed in comments (Machin's classic one)
- $2\tan^{-1}\frac13+\tan^{-1}\frac17=\frac\pi4$

So $m\tan^{-1}\frac12+n\tan^{-1}\frac15=\frac\pi4$ has no solution in integers, or even rational numbers.